# Update cursor values dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, cursor

I am using a `Cursor` in my query.

However I am inserting rows into the same table I am looping on. 
But the cursor is not updating my results into the needed results. So I have to run my query once again to add the needed fields again.

In my query I intend to insert the rawitems of a manufactuered item added by the user. However those added raw items might be manufactured as well, so I need to insert their raw items too after them being added. That's why I need my cursor to be updated each time I add a line.

Am I missing something?

My cursor query is like the following:

```
DECLARE c_RawItmCursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT tbLines.LinesID
FROM dbo.tbLines
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    Select TID, ItmID, UnitID
    From tbLines
    Where TID = @ISTransID
    AND IsRawMaterial = 0 AND ItmType = 2
)tb
ON tb.TID = tbLines.TID
AND tb.ItmID = tbLines.ItmID
AND tb.UnitID = tbLines.UnitID
WHERE tbLines.TID = @ISTransID
AND tbLines.IsRawMaterial = 1
AND tbLines.ItmType = 2
and tb.TID IS NULL

OPEN c_RawItmCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM c_RawItmCursor into @ISTransLinesID
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbLines ...
```

Now I want my cursor to loop also on the new added rows.

I tried to add `DYNAMIC` but also didn't work.

Comment: I just tested similar thing.i don't think here cursor type is important.you hv to show rest part of your script.and what you are trying to ?have you applied logic to break cursor loop ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh Thanks will update my quest in a minute

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21239784. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a short heads up, I will quickly delete this comment.

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227159/dynamic-cursor-not-reflecting-updates-to-base-table) - it appears there are conditions which convert a dynamic cursor to a static one - I don't know what the other conditions are, but maybe you've run into one. You can potentially see by checking the execution plan.